# Exporting database with Zotero so urls will be exported to bibtex with \url command

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, lyx, urls, zotero

When exporting a database or collection within Zotero to BibTeX, a URL will not be enclosed with the `\url` command, thus rendering links not clickable in Lyx when `hyperref` enabled. Is it possible to make Zotero exporting url's with the 
`\url`  command automatically?

Comment: What is the field name containing the URL? If it's done 'properly', LaTeX will treat URLs correctly, but that requires they are stored as `url` fields.

Comment: Well, that's the problem: zotero does not export them as url fields. No Zotero settings to be found on that either. Typical entry: `@misc{shortcodeyear,
 title = {Title of page},
 url = {http://domain.com/path/to/page},
 journal = {Website},
 month = sep,
 year = {2012},
 howpublished = {http://domain.com/path/to/page},
 file = {/path/to/file}`

Comment: That sounds like an out-and-out Zotero issue, which is likely to make the question 'off-topic' for us. While you want to use your data with Lyx, the expertise needed here is at the Zotero end.

Answer (score 2):

Zotero does export URLs in a URL field.  As per your example, it includes:

```
url={http://domain.com/path/to/page}
```

This will create clickable links if you have a BST file that supports the `url` field and uses `\url` or `\href` automatically.

Comment: Do you have to do anything in particular to get this to happen? The questioner suggests in a comment that no `url` field is generated: is there an equivalent one in Zotero that has to be filled out?

Comment: This happens automatically.  Look at grrrbytes's comment again: the "typical entry" includes the URL field.  The issue is most likely with the BST file that is being used.